# Make non-Future Rust function into a Future function?

Tags: rust, cassandra, parquet

I inherited a Rust application and I wish to make a small modification to it. Presently, it retrieves records from Cassandra in the following way using Futures:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Item {
    pub a: String,
    pub b: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum DataSetError {
    CassandraError(cassandra_cpp::Error),
}

pub type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, DataSetError>;


pub fn select_cass_items(
    session: &Session,
    a: String,
) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<Item>>> + Unpin {
    let table = envmnt::get_or("TABLE", "ab_table");
    let mut statement = stmt!(&("SELECT a, b FROM ".to_owned() + &table + " WHERE a = ?"));
    statement.bind(0, a).unwrap();

    session.execute(&statement).map(|result| {
        result
            .map(|rows| {
                rows.iter()
                    .map(|row| Item {
                        a: row.get_by_name("a").unwrap(),
                        b: row.get_by_name("b").unwrap(),
                    })
                    .collect()
            })
            .map_err(|e| {
                warn!("[select_cass_items] {:?}", e);
                DataSetError::CassandraError(e)
            })
    })
}
```

I want to add the option of doing the same thing but from Parquet files. I have written a simple non-Future function (below) that does the equivalent reading/filtering operation as the Cassandra function. I've verified it works as intended.

```
pub fn read_parquet_file (
        a: String)
    -> Vec<Item> {
        let reader = SerializedFileReader::try_from("/path/to/file.parquet".to_string()).unwrap();
        let iter = reader.get_row_iter(None).unwrap();

        iter.filter_map(|row| {
            if row.get_string(0).unwrap() == &a {
                Some(Item {
                    a: row.get_string(0).unwrap().to_string(),
                    b: row.get_double(1).unwrap(),
                })
            }
            else {
                None
            }
        }).collect::<Vec<_>>()


}
```

The question is: **how do I convert the non-Future Parquet function to be a drop-in replacement for the Future Cassandra function?** I see that the [cassandra_cpp](https://docs.rs/cassandra-cpp/0.15.1/cassandra_cpp/) crate supports Futures, but the [parquet](https://crates.io/crates/parquet) create does not. Surely there must be a way to do this? However, I'm a Rust newbie, and I can't find any examples close enough to what I want to be able to mogrify my work into what I need. I've tried various things but they've all been dead ends, and aren't worth sharing.

Thank you!

Comment: You can `block_on` the function so it runs in another thread or task, and get a future of the result of that.

Comment: Don't just wrap the code in async because then it will block the current task.